# How to design a simple proxy server that reads configuration files and blocks some websites?

Tags: c#, configuration-files, proxy-server

Hi i was thinking to build simple proxy server for my flat so that our flatmates are not spending hours and hours downloading stuff, streaming on youtube and eating all the bandwidth. How am i going to build a simple proxy server so that i can restrict other flatmates going on some particular sites.
I was thinking to use some kind configurable file and list the name of the site that are going to be restricted.
the question is, where do i start form ? can anyone help me to generate an algorithm to build a simple server ?

Thanks

Comment: How would you force them to use that "proxy"?

Comment: Why do you think you are in position to limit other's access to internet by the way?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off using [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) and having [SQUID Proxy Server](http://www.squid-cache.org/) configured on the system from which you are sharing internet to other systems, rather than implementing your own solution as it is a very complex task to implement a proxy server which provides a decent level of security.

Comment: that's the other reason i want to design it for, to get to know what kind of security issue will i come across and how to manage them and also, i think it will be more fun to do something by myself rather than buying one of the self.

Comment: You would need to maintain a blacklist and check if the request is in any of them. If not you can forward the request and send it back. The problem is, people can use other proxy servers to bypass your proxy. You would also need it to be very fast as all traffic goes through that. BTW SQUID and OpenDNS are free

Comment: HTTP proxies won't do anything against non-HTTP protocols (FTP, Torrent, etc.). And the moment you allow CONNECT method on your proxy (so HTTPS could work through it), your proxy becomes essentially useless for restricting access.